# How do I figure out the difference between these 2 options of RAM?

Tags: memory, hardware-rec

I am building a computer and have found two virtually identical (in my view) options for RAM:

- [Option 1](http://ncix.ca/products/?sku=44264&vpn=F3-10666CL9D-8GBRL&manufacture=G.Skill): "G.SKILL F3-10666CL9D-8GBRL Ripjaws 8GB 2X4GB DDR3-1333 CL9-9-9-24 240PIN DIMM Memory"
- [Option 2](http://ncix.com/products/?sku=57950): "G.SKILL Ripjaws X F3-10666CL9D-8GBXL 8GB 2X4GB DDR3-1333 CL9-9-9-24 Memory"

My motherboard is an [Intel BOXDP67DEB3](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?item=N82E16813121512).

What's the difference between the two options?

Comment: Difference as in what? What apples are you oranging about?

Comment: They look like the exact same RAM to me.  I'm wondering how they're different at all.  I can see that the model numbers are ever so slightly different.  Will one work with my motherboard while the other won't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about compatibility.

Option 2 is newer and slightly more expensive as a result.  It supports the Intel P67 whereas Option 1 does not.  In terms of performance, they are both identical from the technical specifications listed on the website.

As your motherboard is Intel P67, you should get Option 2.

Comment: This is what I thought, and exactly the reassurance I needed.  Thanks!